# Как перебрать элементы списка через свойства созданного класса

Tags: python, классы, list, перебор

Здесь мне помогли с созданием классов, поэтому у меня и появились затруднения. Сначала создается класс Point со свойствами х, у и цвет. Далее мы заполняем список points свойствами класса Point.
Проблема состоит в том, что в конце мне надо перебрать элементы из списка points по свойству х класса Point. То есть по сути перебрать точки с координатами Х. Но вот как это сделать, я не понимаю. Пытаюсь сделать это в строке for i in range(points). Также там есть сторонние функции, списки и всякие цвета, но на них не обращайте внимания, это не суть.

```
    class Point:

        number = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
        color = "red"

    j = 4
    points = [[ ]  for i in range(j)]
    gx1 = -10
    gx2 = 10
    gy1 = -10
    gy2 = 15

    tol = 5

    YT[0] = list(range(gx1, gx2))
    colors = ["green", "yellow", "blue", "tomato", "pink", "lime", 
    "deeppink", "brown"] 

    for l in range(j):

        for i in range(gx1, gx2):
            r = gy1+tol*l+tol
            if l == j - 1:
                r = gy2
    
            for o in range(gy1+tol*l, r):           
        
                p = Point()
                p.color = colors[l]
                p.x = i
                p.y = o
                points[l].append(p)
                a.scatter(p.x, p.y, c = p.color)

    def SmestitelFunc(x, n):
        return 5*np.arctan(x - n*rastnad)

    blocks = [[] for i in range(w + 1)]

    for i in range(points):
            for h in range(w):

                 nad1 = SmestitelFunc(i, h)
                 nad2 = SmestitelFunc(i, h + 1)

                 for u in range(p.y):
                     if u > nad1 and u < nad2:
                         blocks[h].append(u)
                         print(blocks)
```

Comment: пожалуйста уберите картинки и приведите примеры обычным текстом.

Comment: так еще и тему светлую скинул, диверсант..